# Value of $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{ e^{-1} }{2^{n^2}} \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty{\frac{n^k}{k!}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, summation

Let $$a_n = \frac{ e^{-1} }{2^{n^2}} \sum_{k = 0}^\infty{\frac{n^k}{k!}}$$Evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$ (If $a_n$ is divergent prove it) . Unfortunately , I'm not familiar with integral .I looked for a pattern in the sequence , no result again . So I'm really confused about solving this problem .

Comment: Dobinski's formula would be for $\sum k^n/k!$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Thanks , I fixed it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know

$$ e^n= \sum_{k = 0}^\infty\frac{n^k}{k!}$$
Hence,
$$a_n =\frac{ e^{-1} }{2^{n^2}} \sum_{k = 0}^\infty{\frac{n^k}{k!}}= \frac{ e^{-1}*e^n}{2^{n^2}} =\frac{  e^{n-1}}{e^{n^2\ln2}} = e^{-n^2\ln2+ n-1}\to 0 $$

Since $$\lim_{n\to\infty}-n^2\ln2+ n-1 =-\infty$$

Answer (score 1):

We have $a_n = \frac{1/e \times \sum_{k = 0}^\infty{\frac{n^k}{k!}}}{2^{n^2}}=\frac{e^{n-1}}{2^{n^2}}$.

It is easy to see that $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \to 0$. Hence $ \sum a_n$ is convergent, and therefore $a_n \to 0$.